# How can i create two targets in swift

Tags: swift, xcode

First target
I have a one todo application having offline save capability ie coredata

Second target
App name, logo change from first one but expect that all the feature inharted from first one also having online data saving capability ie. Firebase

Main issue is how can i create class and use second one firebase

Comment: Just create target create classes same as you creating before right inspector have a TargetMembership box check or uncheck target for a specific class. 
For assets add one more asset file check Target member ship of that file to second target.

Comment: I am creating using same but how to manage firebase file and controller